# Why Git merge command gives me different ouptut

Tags: git, git-merge

I have been working with Git for a year now and I stumbled upon a confusing thing today while merging the branches. Here is the .config file section on my local :

```
[branch "develop"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/develop

[branch "Feature/Sprint4.4/mybranch"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/Feature/Sprint4.4/mybranch
```

Now I am on local branch mybranch. I executed following commands in sequence.

```
1) git pull
 --> 2d6cf1e..655001e  develop    -> origin/develop
 --> already up-to-date
2) git merge origin develop
 --> already up-to-date
3) git merge origin/develop
 --> merge made by recursive strategy...
     ....(all the changes were indicated)
      7 files changed, 202 insertions(+), 181 deletions(-)
```

My question is what is the exact difference between command (2) and (3) above and why the outputs changed?

I know I can go through Git docs and other books but looking for an answer simpler language.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756614/difference-between-git-merge-origin-master-and-git-pull)?

Comment: `git merge origin develop` will merge origin into your local master. `git merge origin/develop` will merge origin/develop into your local mybranch.

Comment: @Jan I don't think the link you gave is relevant I as I am doing pull and then using merge with different semantics and that's what I want to know the difference.

Comment: @Foolish I didn't get what you mean by local master there is no master branch for me. there is only develop and other local branches. What does the develop argument in command (2) mean if it merges the changes into local master?

Comment: Sorry I mean `develop`. Consider it develop not master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this is already answered and accepted but I think there's a crucial bit missing from the accepted answer.

#### You almost never want to run `git merge` with more than *one* additional argument.

In other words, `git merge origin develop` is rarely a good idea; don't do that.  To see why, read on.

---

### `git pull` and `git merge` take different arguments

It's true (i.e., it's correct) that `git pull` simply runs `git fetch` followed by `git merge` (or, if you instruct it, `git pull` followed by `git rebase`).  The tricky part is *how* it runs them, and that the `pull` command generally takes *two* arguments:

`$ git pull remote refspec`

but the `merge` command generally takes *one*:

`$ git merge commit`

**Note that the names here (*`remote`*, *`refspec`*, and *`commit`*) are all different:** this is one of the keys to understanding the commands.  Also, note the word "generally" when talking about the number of arguments used: it's possible to omit some arguments sometimes, or to use more arguments.

#### What is a "remote"?

In its simplest form, a remote is just a name like `origin` that refers to an entry in your git config file (`.git/config`).  The `pull` script has a long history of alternative ways to use it, so you can put other things here, but as long as you just use these names, things work pretty well and are less confusing, so let's leave it at that.

#### What is a "refspec"?

A complete refspec has up to three parts.  All three matter a lot with `git push` but much less so with `git fetch`, and since `git pull` runs `git fetch`, we can use the simplest version, which is just a branch or tag name.  When using `git fetch` (and therefore also `git pull`), the branch name you supply is the name of the branch *on the remote*.  Hence:

`git pull origin branch`

makes your git contact the remote `origin` and ask it about its branch named *`branch`*.

Assuming the branch name exists on the remote, your git will obtain the latest version of that branch (and, generally, update `refs/remotes/origin/branch` as well, at least if you have git version 1.8.4 or newer—that is, with newer versions of git, your "remote-tracking branches" always get updated).

As a side effect that `git pull` relies on, `git fetch` *also* writes all its updated branch information<sup>1</sup> to a file called `FETCH_HEAD` in git's private (`.git`) directory.  The only thing you really need to know about this is that the `pull` script uses it (but you can read the contents of the file if you like).

**Summary so far: `git pull` runs `git fetch` and stores updates in `FETCH_HEAD`**, and sometimes also in your "remote-tracking branches" like `origin/master` and `origin/develop` and so on.

---

#### Using `git merge`

Now let's move on to `git merge`.

I said above that it "generally" takes three arguments, `git merge commit`.

The `pull` command always gives `merge` three arguments (and a lot of flags, including some flags to supply the merge commit message).  The `pull` script gets the *commit* argument—and, for that matter, the merge commit message—out of the `FETCH_HEAD` file.<sup>2</sup>

If you wanted to do this manually, you could do it the same way the `pull` script does, but extracting and typing in long SHA-1 IDs is painful.  And, in any case, what you wanted to do was to merge a different, *local* branch, not the raw SHA-1 of a commit brought over by a `fetch` step.

Here's where you went wrong initially, when you entered the command:

> ```
> git merge origin develop
> ```

This passes *two* arguments to `merge`.  They are both taken as commit IDs and this tells `git merge` to do something called an "octopus merge".  Unless you're an advanced git master, you probably don't want to do that.  (Luckily, in your case, there was nothing to do anyway, given the multiple commit IDs you gave to git.)

I will note here that `origin` does *not* look like a commit-ID, and `develop` doesn't resemble an SHA-1 either.  But in fact, both of these names *do* name specific commits—if they didn't, you would have gotten an error message from your `git merge` command.  To find out *which* commits, you can use the command `git rev-parse`:

```
$ git rev-parse origin
a17c56c056d5fea0843b429132904c429a900229
```

(yours won't match this SHA-1, but the idea should be clear enough).  The branch name also resolves to a raw SHA-1—I don't have a `develop` but I do have `master` and `origin/master` so I will use those here:

```
$ git rev-parse master
a17c56c056d5fea0843b429132904c429a900229
$ git rev-parse origin/master
a17c56c056d5fea0843b429132904c429a900229
```

(in this case, the two are the same as my `master` is now up to date with `origin/master`).

In general, a branch name resolves to the commit at the tip of the branch.

I'll repeat that, because it's another key to understanding git.  **A branch name resolves to the commit at the tip of the branch,** with one very big and very important exception, which is when doing `git checkout`.   Since `git checkout` is one of the first things people do with git, they learn that branch names are special—which is true for `git checkout`, but not for most other git commands.  Most commands just turn the name into a raw SHA-1, and when they do, they get the tip of the branch.

> ```
> git merge origin/develop
> ```

Running `git merge` with a symbolic name, like `origin/develop`, is quite reasonable: git will look up the raw commit ID for you, and will set up the default merge message to use the symbolic name, which will mean more to a human reading the log later.  If you use the raw commit ID you'll get that in the log.

**Summary for merge:** `git merge origin/develop` is a reasonable thing to do.  It means "find the tip commit of `origin/develop` and merge that, as a regular merge."  However, `git merge origin develop` is *not* a good idea as it means "find the tip commits of `origin` and `develop` and do an octopus merge of those two commits."

---

<sup>1</sup>When you use the four-argument form, `git fetch remote refspec`, the `fetch` step brings over *only* the one branch you ask for.  With three arguments, i.e., `git fetch remote`, the `fetch` step normally brings over all branches.  With just two arguments, `git fetch` generally fetches from `origin` automatically as needed, and again brings over all branches.  Therefore, you can generally just run `git fetch`.

<sup>2</sup>If you examine the file you'll see something like this:

```
a17c56c056d5fea0843b429132904c429a900229        branch 'master' of [url]
```

You might also see more lines, e.g.:

```
ca00f80b58d679e59fc271650f68cd25cdb72b09    not-for-merge   branch 'maint' of [url]
```

(or you might not)—this is all the stuff `git fetch` brought over.  In this particular case, I ran `git pull` with no arguments and it brought over `master` and `maint` (and a few more items).  All the commit IDs wind up in `FETCH_HEAD` and then the `pull` script extracts the one that *is* "for merge" by excluding all the ones marked "not-for-merge".

Answer (score 1):

You are on `mybranch`

```
1) git pull  // This will pull changes from origin and write them into your my branch.(It will fetch for your develop branch)
 --> 2d6cf1e..655001e  develop    -> origin/develop
 --> already up-to-date
2) git merge origin develop  // This will take almost no effect as you already pulled as it shows develop -> origin/develop
                            // This is same as git merge origin/develop develop
 --> already up-to-date
3) git merge origin/develop  // This will merge changes from origin/develop to mybranch
                             // This is same as git merge origin/develop mybranch
 --> merge made by recursive strategy...
     ....(all the changes were indicated)
      7 files changed, 202 insertions(+), 181 deletions(-)
```