# How do I manage local branch and remote after push feature branch?

Tags: git

My `master` branch of remote repository does not accept commits directly. So I am creating a new local repository names `feature/xyz` and commit it.

After commits, I am pushing it using command `git push -u origin feature/xyz`. And creating pull request on remote and merge it in remote `master` branch. So the local `master` is old now.

Should I pull remote master or merge local feature/xyz branch? Which is right way?

Answer (score 0):

The right approach will be to pull the remote master. See the detailed explanation in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21758295/4311135